# error Failed to get dependency config. while installing fonts

Tags: react-native

I am trying to install fonts with 
react-native link ./assets/fonts/ and with react-native link
both are giving the same error:
"error Failed to get dependency config."

I updated my package.json

"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }

Please help

I have made sure the path to the font folder is correct and still same problem

Comment: same issue, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

re-install and re-link solves the problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

What version of your react-native?

If it is> 0.60, it is recommended to create the react-native.config.js file with the configurations below:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: [
    './assets/fonts/',
  ],
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Link without specifying the package name and it should work

```
react-native link
```